# how to set destination directory in crontab, with cpanel

Tags: cron

I want to use cron to download and unzip then move to direcotry in my server,

what i did:

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz -
|gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz &&
mv GeoLiteCity.dat 37.18.176.133/~work/wp-content/plugins/shabatkeeper/GeoLiteCity.dat
```

what i get:

```
  --2014-12-22 11:00:03-- 
  http://-/ Resolving -... failed: Name or service not known. 
  wget: unable to resolve host address `-'
  FINISHED --2014-12-22 11:00:03--
  Downloaded: 1 files, 11M in 1.1s (10.7 MB/s)
```

how to set destination directory?

**Answer** - what id did:

1. downloaded the file with

   `wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz`
2. entered cpanel file browser and check where the file `GeoLiteCity.dat.gz` is.

3.then saw which directory was home and how its called and found the the path i needed is
`/home/work/www/`

that's it

Comment: What version shell and OS are you running? Please edit that into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for

wget -q -O- http://geolite.maxmind.com/wnload/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz | gunzip > /path/to/where/you/want/GeoLiteCity.dat

Comment: tx for ur answer itryes and i get:   `/bin/sh: http://37.18.176.133/~work/wp-content/plugins/shabatkeeper/GeoLiteCity.dat: No such file or directory`

Comment: http://37.18.176.133/~work/wp-content/plugins/shabatkeeper/GeoLiteCity.dat isn't the correct path on the filesystem.  It will be something like /home/username/www or /var/www/~work

Comment: thanks for ur answer, how can i find the correct path